# Return only the measurements of a circuit

Tags: programming, qiskit, measurement

I have written the following program in jupyter:

```
from qiskit import *
from qiskit import plot_histogram, matplotlib

circuit = QuantumCircuit(16,16) #Making a circuit with 16 qubits
qr = QuantumRegister(16)
cr = ClassicalRegister(16)
for i in range(16):
    circuit.h(i)
    circuit.measure(i,i)

simulator = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
result = execute(circuit, backend = simulator, shots = 200).result()
counts = result.get_counts()
print(counts)
```

and the output is of the form :

```
{'0111001100011110': 1, '0101000101101001': 1, '1100010111000100': 1, 
'0111111110101110': 1,..., '0110110010010110': 1}
```

Is there any way that what I get as an output is the measurement only (e.g. '0111001100011110')  without getting the times the measurement has appeared (: 1)?

Comment: A bit of a side note: `circuit.h(qr); circuit.measure(qr, cr)` is equivalent to that for-loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take only the keys of the returned dictionary:

```
measurements = set(counts.keys())
print(measurements)
```

If you want only one random key, you can just take the first one in the set:

```
random_key = next(iter(a))
```

or store all the keys in a list and take a random one from here:

```
from random import randint
measurements_list = list(measurements)
random_key = measurement_list[randint(0, len(measurement_list)-1)]
```

Comment: Thank you. That is exactly what I needed!